# print the line, then the last word twice

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following file (F1):

```
if a equals b
you
three aggbc four
```

I want the output to be:

```
if a equals b b b
you you you
three aggbc four four four
```

I run the following command:

```
sed -re 's/.*([^ ]+)[ |$]/\0 \1 \1/' F1
```

But it wont work.

The output I get is wrong:

```
if a equals  s sb
you
three aggbc  c cfour
```

I need it as a `sed` command.

Comment: `But it wont work.` What did it do?

Comment: The post it updated with the output I get.

Comment: With `awk` would be veeery fast: `awk '{print $0, $NF, $NF}' file`

Comment: I need it in 'sed' unfortunately....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^(.* )?(.*)$/\1\2 \2 \2/' F1
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex specials lose their special meaning inside a character class. So `[ |$]` matches a single character which can be space, pipe, or dollar sign. Try this instead;

```
sed -re 's/.*([^ ]+) *$/& \1 \1/' F1
```

Also notice that I changed `\0` to `&`. I haven't seen `\0` in `sed` but if yours supports it, more power to you.

Comment: For the line with only `you` string, it doesn't work because the initial `.*` is greedy. It will match until the end and will begin to trackback until a match so it will only repeat last letter, not the whole word.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I upvoted @JoyRe's answer but leave this for the explanation.

Comment: But you can fix it. You could make it to backtrack until a space or until the beginning adding `([ ]|^)` just before do grouping over the last word and use `\2` in the replacement part, like: `sed -re 's/.*([ ]|^)([^ ]+) *$/& \2 \2/' infile`

Comment: Thanks again. I'm still too lazy (-:

Answer (score 0):

If you are interesting to learn awk, here it is:

```
awk '{print $0 FS $NF FS $NF}' file

awk '{$NF=$NF FS $NF FS $NF}1' file
```